# Magento Migration tool concern

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

In reading the documentation for the Magento migration tool I see that it is in multiple parts with separate commands. I've already created the settings manually in my new M2 store. I just want the data(products, attributes, etc...)

Can I run the data migration on its own so I'm just moving product data?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307747/can-i-still-use-magento-1-9-theme-at-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

In order to get products data only, in your config.xml file of data migration tool, add below steps

```
<steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>

        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version11410to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>

        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>

        <step title="VisualMerchandiser Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\VisualMerchandiser\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>tep>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
```

and run data migration command with reset. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does my source and destination tags go after that?

Comment: yes, this is how it should be setup https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/blob/2.2-develop/etc/commerce-to-commerce/1.14.3.9/config.xml.dist